# jhipster maven run error

Tags: maven, jhipster

getting below error when using jhipster to run the server application

```
mvnw
```

> Blockquotejava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13292
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2502)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:1604)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1434)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1131)
>           at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:3856)
>           at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:595)

Comment: Remember to add the Jhipster version you're using, which architecture and database you chose ...

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well and ended up deleting my Maven local repository folder

- Unix/MacOS: `~/.m2/`
- Windows - `C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2`

and reimported the Maven project and then ran `./mvnw` and it worked!